# What Monitoring Dashboards do exist with customizable actions like handles, levers and actionable buttons?

Tags: monitoring

Are there DevOps web dashboards (open-source preferably) or dashboard frameworks that allow setting up custom buttons, levers which execute custom actions from browser?

Think of "Plus" button which adds new AWS server, or "Maintenance" button which announces maintenance on Slack and locks automated cluster changes.

Sure, those should be baked up by backend command execution center.

Comment: I was half looking for the same, but can this not be done with a standard Web framework and fontawesome buttons?

Comment: sure, the question is whether it's possible to minimize amount of written code.

Comment: Maybe check [cachetHQ](https://cachethq.io/) ? IIRC you can hook commands with components statuses

Comment: Could you reply to the comment?